# Simple Ruby Programing, getting error and don't understand why, need complete description

Tags: ruby

I'm really new in ruby, and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mqrg6m0pxa15taw/projectx.pdf) is the description of what I asked to do,

when I run this program I get following error, It would be great if someone could explain that error because I spent so many hours trying to figuring it out but no luck.

Thank you.

Error:

```
v = [1, 2, 3]
v1 = [2, 3, 4]
v * v1 = 20
D:/Project/hwk7.rb:33:in `block in each2': undefined method `[]' for #<MyMatrix:0x00000002c12468> (NoMethodError)
    from D:/Project/hwk7.rb:32:in `times'
    from D:/Project/hwk7.rb:32:in `each2'
    from D:/Project/hwk7.rb:41:in `*'
    from D:/Project/hwk7.rb:104:in `<main>'
m = [#<MyVector:0x00000002c12418 @array=[1, 2]>, #<MyVector:0x00000002c123f0 @array=[1, 2]>, #<MyVector:0x00000002c123c8 @array=[1, 2]>]
```

My Code:

```
# MyVector Class
class  MyVector
  include Enumerable
  def initialize (a)
    if !(a.instance_of? Array)
      raise "ARGUMENT OF INITIALIZER MUST BE AN ARRAY"
    else
      @array = a
    end
  end

  def array
    @array
  end

  def to_s
    @array.to_s
  end

  def length
    @array.length
  end

  def [](i)
    @array[i]
  end

  def each2(a)
    raise Error, "INTEGER IS NOT LIKE VECTOR" if a.kind_of?(Integer)
    Vector.Raise Error if length != a.length
    return to_enum(:each2, a) unless block_given?
    length.times do |i|
      yield @array[i], a[i]
    end
    self
  end

  def * (a)
    Vector.Raise Error if length != a.length
    p = 0
    each2(a) {|a1, a2|p += a1 * a2}
    p
  end
end

# MyMatrix Class
class MyMatrix
  include Enumerable
  def initialize a
    @array=Array.new(a.length)
    i=0
    while(i<a.length)
      @array[i]=MyVector.new(a[i])
      i+=1
    end
  end

  def to_s
    @array.to_s
  end

  def length
    @array.length()
  end

  def transpose
    size=vectors[0].length
    arr= Array.new(size)
    i=0
    while i<size
      a=Array.new(vector.length)
      j=0
      while j<a.length
        a[j]=vectors[j].arr[i]
        j+=1
      end
      arr[i]=a
      i+=1
    end
    arr[i]=a
    i+=1
  end

  def *m
    if !(m instance_of? MyMatrix)
      raise Error
      a=Array.new(@array.length)
      i=0
      while (i<@array.length)
        a[i]=@array[i]*m
        i=i+1
      end
    end
  end
end

v = MyVector.new([1,2,3])
puts "v = " + v.to_s
v1 = MyVector.new([2,3,4])
puts "v1 = " + v1.to_s
puts "v * v1 = " + (v * v1).to_s
m = MyMatrix.new([[1,2], [1, 2], [1, 2]])
puts "m = " + m.to_s + "\n"
puts "v * m = " + (v * m).to_s
m1 = MyMatrix.new([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]])
puts "m1 = " + m1.to_s + "\n"
puts "m * m1 = " + (m * m1).to_s
puts "m1 * m = " + (m1 * m).to_s
```

Comment: why are you trying to multiply a matrix with a vector???, secondly you did not define a `[]` method for your matrix

Comment: Please read the full description of task: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mqrg6m0pxa15taw/projectx.pdf Thank you

Comment: @bjhaid I added the [] method but I get another error.
v * v1 = 20
m = [#<MyVector:0x00000002ba20f0 @array=[1, 2]>, #<MyVector:0x00000002ba20c8 @array=[1, 2]>, #<MyVector:0x00000002ba20a0 @array=[1, 2]>]
D:/Project/hwk7.rb:41:in `*': MyVector can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
 from D:/Project/hwk7.rb:41:in `block in *'
 from D:/Project/hwk7.rb:33:in `block in each2'
 from D:/Project/hwk7.rb:32:in `times'
 from D:/Project/hwk7.rb:32:in `each2'
 from D:/Project/hwk7.rb:41:in `*'
 from D:/Project/hwk7.rb:108:in `<main>'

Comment: it is not my business to read your task, I am only here to help, I have pointed out what the faults I can identify in your code which I assume is the best I can do for you, I would not attempt to write your homework for you

Comment: @bjhaid If I wanted you to do my homework then I would not post what I have done !!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you perform `v * m`, `v` which is an instance of `MyVector` pulls out its `*` method to do the job. This method calls on its turn `each2` with the same set argument that `*` received . During `each2` execution, code sends the `[]` method on each looping iteration you do to the very same argument you sent to `*`. In our case, it is the object `m` that takes this role in this loop as a substitute for `a`:

```
# each 2 method fragment
length.times do |i|
  yield @array[i], a[i]
end
```

m is an instance of `MyMatrix` which unfortunately does not declare any `[]` method anywhere. If you dive in source of class Array you will most probably find a `[]` method. But here it is missing and Ruby throws you the `undefined method [] for #<MyMatrix:0x00000002c12468> (NoMethodError)` you got.